# Sum of remaining of 2^k divided by 2003

Tags: geometry, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Sorry for my interruption. I am looking for an answer to this question: Calculating 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2002}r_k$$ in which $r_k$ is the remaining of $2^k$ divided by $2003$.
I thought that $2$ was a primitive root of $2003$, but I was wrong, in fact $ord_{2003}(2) = 286$. I hope you can help me on this question.

Comment: @lulu: Yes. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use geometric series for $2^k$.

Solution: (Hover to reveal)

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{2002}{r_k}=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2002}{2^k}\right) \pmod{2003}$$
>  $$=\frac{2(1-2^{2002})}{-1}=2^{2003}-2$$
>  By the geometric series formula.
>  Note that 2003 is prime so by Fermat's Little Theorem, $2^{2003}-2 \equiv 0 \pmod{2003}$

Comment: Actually, I was looking for the actual sum, for example: r_1 = 2, r_2 = 4, r_3 = 232 then r_1 + r_2+r_3 = 2+4+232=238. But thank you for your answer and sorry for the misunderstandings?

Comment: I don't understand, doesn't $r_3$ equal the remainder when $2^3=8$ is divided by $2003$?

Comment: That just an example, what I mean is to calculate the sum, not the mod, r_1+r_2+r_3+r_4+... = 2+4+8+16+...=a number.

Comment: But in fact the sum of the mods is the mod of the sum. i.e $r_1+r_2+r_3+...+r_{2002}=(2^1 \pmod{2003})+(2^2 \pmod{2003})+(2^3 \pmod{2003})+...+(2^{2002} \pmod{2003})=\left(\sum_{n=1}^{2002}{2^k}\right) \pmod{2003}$

Comment: If $r_1+r_2+r_3+... = n$, and $n = 0 (mod 2003)$, then the answer is $n$, not $0$. $r_1+r_2+... +r_{10}=2+4+...+1024=2046.$